# How can I issue an HTTP POST request using only standard Perl libraries?

Tags: perl

Assume a system that contains only the basic Perl installation without any extra CPAN modules (LWP is hence **NOT** installed). Some of my target environments have limited space and I cannot increase my footprint at all (otherwise I would use LWP).

What is the most portable and reliable way to issue a HTTP POST request from such a system, and then retrieve the response?

Comment: Why would you possibly be in this situation?

Comment: Ether: I'm not in control of the target environment.

Comment: Package LWP with your code and don't be ridiculous

Comment: zakovyrya: Which part of "installing LWP is not an option" is it that you don't understand?

Comment: @knorv, the whole point is that you DON'T have to install LWP if you package it with your code, e.g. using PAR

Comment: friedo: LWP+dependencies does not even FIT in some of the environments targeted. If packaging and/or installing LWP was an option I would not have asked this question.

Comment: No, the thing is you don't understand all your options.
Install LWP using CPAN into local directory. Take a look at this module: http://search.cpan.org/~apeiron/local-lib-1.004007/lib/local/lib.pm

Comment: zkovyrya: LWP+dependencies does not even fit in some of the environments targeted.

Comment: Is HTML::Parser C code a problem for you? Maybe it is possible to make LWP run without it.

Comment: Yes, wrong question.  How do I bolt a minimal library that already exists into my as-small-as-possible code is the correct question.  I think you want HTTP::Lite as mentioned below though.

Comment: Re: "Installing...NOT an option. I thought that was obvious from the title and the question" - very often people are mistaken when they start out claiming they can't use external modules, so you can expect a lot of guidance in that direction when you ask such a question.  Don't let it upset you; folks are just trying to be maximally helpful.

Comment: If LWP's source won't fit, why are you using Perl? That's a big footprint for such a small environment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[HTTP::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Lite) is pure-Perl, so you can just bundle it along with your existing code.

Comment: Or HTTP::Tiny, which supersedes HTTP::Lite

Comment: Both libraries still include MUCH more functionality (=code=ballast) than the poster probably needs. On embedded systems, every byte is scarce. I also prefer coding only the necessary functions by hand if I only need 10% of what libraries provide.

Answer (score 12):

Consider this. HTTP POSTs are not trivial. You need to assemble the data into a MIME blob, encode it properly, then open a Socket connection, send the data, then read any response headers from the socket to make sure it worked.

You'll be doing a lot of work to duplicate what LWP already does, and then you'll take all that work and put it in your environment that doesn't have LWP.

At that point, you will ask yourself, "gee, if I can put my *own* Perl code on this environment, why can't I just put LWP there?"

Never fear, for I am here to save you three months of useless work.

[How to install Perl modules locally](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2002/04/10/mod_perl.html)

If you can't do that, then

[How to use PAR to package and distribute dependencies](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PAR::Tutorial)

Good luck, and don't duplicate code.

Answer (score 3):

I just do HTTP Post like this without using any library,

```
sub post {
    local($host,$port,$request,$data) = @_;
    ($fqdn, $aliases, $type, $len, $thataddr) = gethostbyname($host);
    $that = pack($sockaddr, &AF_INET, $port, $thataddr);
    socket(FS, &AF_INET, &SOCK_STREAM, $proto) || return undef;
    bind(FS, $thissock) || return undef;
    local($/);
    unless (eval q!
        $SIG{'ALRM'} = "timeout";
        alarm($timeout);
        connect(FS, $that) || return undef;
        select(FS); $| = 1; select(STDOUT);

        print FS "POST $request HTTP/1.0\r\n$referer";
        print FS "$useragent";
        print FS "Host: $host:$port\r\n$mimeaccept";
        print FS "$cnt_type";
        $len = length($data);
        print FS "Content-length: $len\r\n\r\n$data\r\n";
        undef($page);
        $/ = "\n";
        $_ = <FS>;
        if (m:HTTP/1.0\s+\d+\s+:) { #HTTP/1.0
          while(<FS>) {
            last if /^[\r\n]+$/; # end of header
          }
          undef($/);
          $page = <FS>;
        }
        else {    # old style server reply
          undef($/);
          $page = $_;
          $_ = <FS>;            
          $page .= $_;
        }
        $SIG{'ALRM'} = "IGNORE";
        !) {
            return undef;
        }
    close(FS);
    $page;
}
```

I use this with a real old server (first generation Apache httpd). It doesn't support HTTP/1.1, chunked encoding etc but you get the idea.

Comment: This won't work with use strict. Your timeout handling is broken. Who will do the encoding?

Comment: Why are you using eval STRING instead of eval BLOCK?

Comment: ysth: This is Perl 4 code and maybe block eval did not existed that time.

Comment: This code was written in 1996. That was my most current Perl knowledge so I don't know what you guys are talking about. This was part of my home automation software developed in Perl on a Slackware Linux. Due to the special interface card, I can't upgrade the 486 PC. So I am stuck with the old Linux, Perl etc. It works perfectly fine so I have no reason to use the new fancy features either.

Comment: "my" already existed in 1996. You should use it for declaring variables instead of "local".

Answer (score 3):

See if there are any other programs available that you could call to perform the post. curl, wget, lynx, or Java for example.

Comment: I second this.  If space is really tight, using an external program (possibly compiled without ssl support to reduce dependencies) can be a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP POST is really trivial if you only want to post plain text, which should suffice for most applications.

I use this code which requires only IO::Socket (running on my NAS with perl 5.8.8) to post sensor data (acquired on my LAN via UDP, also via another IO::Socket) to an influxdb server on the internet:

```
my $REMOTE = new IO::Socket::INET (PeerAddr => 'yourhostname.com', PeerPort => '8086',
                                   Proto => 'tcp', Timeout => '1', Blocking => '0')                 
   or die "can't connect - connection busy?";                                                       
$REMOTE->autoflush(1);                                                                              
                                                                                                    
my $data = "POOL ph=$ph,orp=$orp";                                                                
my $len = length($data);                                                                          
print $REMOTE "POST /write?db=esp-sensors HTTP/1.1\n",                              
              "Host: yourhostname.com\n",                                                    
              "Connection: close\n",                                                
              "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n",                  
              "Content-Length: $len\n\n",                                           
              "$data\n";                                                            
close($REMOTE);
```

Granted, I don't check the result. But I assume it would be possible. Since there is nothing I could do about any failure anyway, I don't care if it fails, someday I'll see data missing in the graph and check whats up.